# Check jquery in paths / require.config - Require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'n trying to check jquery load in my project that is loaded or not. But i want to do this in my require.config. I set shim setting like;

```
require.config({
  'paths': {
      'jquery': !window.jQuery ? '../Libraries/jquery-1.10.1.min' : window.jQuery,
      'jqueryui': '../Libraries/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom',
      'underscore': '../Libraries/underscore-1.4.4',
      'mousetrap': '../Libraries/mousetrap-1.4.0'
  },

  shim: {
      'underscore': {
          exports: 'under'
      },
      'jqueryui': ['jquery'],
      'mousetrap': ["jquery"]
  }
});
```

But it's giving error. Require.js is trying get link from function. Can i check jquery in config? Or Should i use another way?

Btw. Error;
*Uncaught Error: Script error
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require-2.1.5.js:159*

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Checkout this http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/basem-emara/2013/03/01/how-to-avoid-loading-jquery-twice-with-requirejs. It might help.